# How to display value from unordered list or table from previous page to next page, and display new values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I have three HTML pages:

- category.html
- type.html
- subType.html

I am trying to achieve two things:-

1. Populate `Category` in type.html according to the category chosen in category.html, and populate `Type` in subType.html according to category chosen in category.html, and type chosen in type.html.
2. I have a flask api url like http://localhost:5000/getInfo?category=categoryName&type=typeName&subtype=subtypeName. 
   How do I pass values of category, type, and subtype from subType.html after a user clicks Get Detail button.

**Category.html:**

```
<head>
  <title>Category Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Please choose one category:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Fruits</li>
      <li>Vegetables</li>
      <li>Clothes</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Type.html:**

```
<head>
  <title>Type Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <h2>Category: Fruits</h2>
    <h3>Please choose a type:</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**SubType.html:**

```
<head>
  <title>Sub Type Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <h2>Category: Fruits</h2>
    <h3>Type: Apple</h3>
    <h4>Please choose Sub-Type:</h4>

    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox">Gala Apple</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox">Cortland</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox">Braeburn</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="button" value="Get Detail" />

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Local Storage, you can achieve this. All modern browsers support local storage. Using cookies also possible.

Using local storage:
setting category:

localStorage.setItem("CategorySelected", "Fruits");

```
Accessing that category in Type.html

    var category=localStorage.getItem("CategorySelected");
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but how can I assign the value of CategorySelected as Fruits? User might click on Vegetables. How can I assign value of CategorySelected as Vegetables when user clicks on Vegetables?

Comment: You can use dropdown  to select Category value or if you want to select from list use on click.